# CSS/JS not updating in Magento

Tags: javascript, css, magento

I edited and uploaded a CSS file to my Magento site. I refreshed the cache and also refreshed the browser cache but I could not see any changes reflected to the site.I noticed that css is updated only for the first time in a day but not after that What should I do?

Comment: As u Said u cleared cache of magento, but Have you cleared cache of server (hosting server) also??

Comment: Or the client browser cache?

Comment: Thanks for the response Niraj,Actually i am not familiar with server cache can you please tell me how to remove server cache.

Comment: and should i have to remove the browser and server cache everytime?

Answer (score 0):

You need to find out any cache extension is active in magento then you need to refresh. If server cache like APC or Varnish cache is installed then You need to refresh it.

Comment: thanks for the response. I haven't installed APC or Varnish cache on my store. I am using merge css and it updates for the first time in a day only.any another solution for this?

Comment: and if in case these are installed on any magento store then should it have to refreshed from server or it can be refreshed from backend or theme files?